# (OSX) launchctl not allowing Python to stop

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, launchd

I use launchctl on Lion (10.7.3) to load 2 instances of SickBeard (a python script) on 2 different ports on system start.

My plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.sickbeard.sickbeard</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
       <string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python</string>
       <string>/Users/james/Applications/Sick-Beard/SickBeard.py</string>
       <string>-q</string>
       <string>-d</string>
  </array>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/sickbeard/sickbeard.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/var/log/sickbeard/sickbeard_error.log</string>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've confirmed that python launches from that location, and that SB is also correct ... indeed both Python instances load correctly on startup - see "top" below.

```
Processes: 94 total, 3 running, 91 sleeping, 450 threads                                                  20:22:54
Load Avg: 6.19, 6.24, 6.39  CPU usage: 94.33% user, 5.66% sys, 0.0% idle
SharedLibs: 82M resident, 0B data, 11M linkedit.
MemRegions: 10801 total, 1189M resident, 40M private, 212M shared.
PhysMem: 927M wired, 1622M active, 3207M inactive, 5757M used, 2435M free.
VM: 222G vsize, 1344M framework vsize, 110371(0) pageins, 89(0) pageouts.
Networks: packets: 1118035/1205M in, 2206764/2119M out. Disks: 323025/15G read, 52125/11G written.

PID   COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH   #WQ  #POR #MRE RPRVT  RSHRD  RSIZE  VPRVT  VSIZE  PGRP PPID STATE    UID
1312  top          5.8   00:00.55 1/1   0    28   38   1044K  216K   1760K  19M    2379M  1312 733  running  0
1246  taskgated    0.0   00:00.01 1     0    30   40   496K   320K   1860K  28M    2388M  1246 1    sleeping 0
1242  mdworker     0.0   00:00.10 3     1    54   70   1540K  13M    5748K  31M    2418M  1242 280  sleeping 89
1241  mdworker     0.0   00:00.98 3     1    50   78   6952K  6252K  12M    28M    2416M  1241 217  sleeping 501
733   bash         0.0   00:00.01 1     0    21   24   288K   760K   1056K  17M    2378M  733  732  sleeping 501
732   sshd         0.0   00:00.02 1     0    13   82   256K   1444K  844K   9740K  2394M  717  717  sleeping 501
717   sshd         0.0   00:00.07 2     1    35   76   488K   1444K  2916K  8884K  2393M  717  1    sleeping 0
703   check_afp    0.0   00:00.02 4     1    44   42   480K   220K   1160K  29M    2389M  703  1    sleeping 0
516   AppleSpell   0.0   00:00.14 2     1    47   52   1172K  5544K  4680K  30M    2412M  516  217  sleeping 501
482   filecoordina 0.0   00:00.02 2     2    38   45   540K   248K   1824K  30M    2390M  482  1    sleeping 0
469   HandBrakeCLI 182.9 01:43:54 22/6  1    79   477  517M   268K   520M   707M   3092M  313  455  running  501
455   bash         0.0   00:00.02 1     0    17   23   216K   756K   888K   9648K  2378M  313  313  sleeping 501
339-  dbfseventsd  0.0   00:01.67 1     0    9    24   20K    324K   176K   20K    583M   314  338  sleeping 501
338-  dbfseventsd  0.0   00:02.03 1     0    9    24   4180K  320K   4372K  12M    591M   314  336  sleeping 0
336-  dbfseventsd  0.0   00:00.43 1     0    16   23   36K    308K   376K   5188K  583M   314  314  sleeping 0
331   Python       0.1   00:16.93 20    0    37   305  63M    2552K  60M    164M   2528M  330  1    sleeping 501
329   Python       0.2   00:20.41 20    0    47   323  55M    2552K  66M    166M   2530M  328  1    sleeping 501
314-  Dropbox      0.0   00:52.95 17    1    116  483  70M    22M    86M    99M    743M   314  217  sleeping 501
313   SABnzbd      7.1   03:41.14 23    1    113  589  170M   22M    203M   219M   2640M  313  217  sleeping 501
312   Alfred       0.0   00:00.38 2     1    110  118  6004K  31M    16M    32M    2472M  312  217  sleeping 501
311   Growl        0.0   00:00.69 5     1    149  129  8636K  21M    18M    165M   3480M  311  217  sleeping 501
```

The problems I have, is that although "launchctl start com.sickbeard.sickbeard" works to start the process, "launchctl stop com.sickbeard.sickbeard" does not stop it.
If I try to launch the autoupdate from the GUI, this fails, prompting me to look at the logs.
The logs include the following at the appropriate time stamp.

```
Mar-24 20:15:25 DEBUG    CP Server Thread-4 :: After checking, cur_commit = a392367b16b197ca59a5017f5ecfb37ade2f26f4, newest_commit = a392367b16b197ca59a5017f5ecfb37ade2f26f4, num_commits_behind = 0
Mar-24 20:15:25 DEBUG    CP Server Thread-4 :: newest: a392367b16b197ca59a5017f5ecfb37ade2f26f4 and current: a392367b16b197ca59a5017f5ecfb37ade2f26f4 and num_commits: 0
AA
Mar-24 20:15:22 DEBUG    CP Server Thread-4 :: Git output: a392367b16b197ca59a5017f5ecfb37ade2f26f4
AA
Mar-24 20:15:22 DEBUG    CP Server Thread-4 :: git output: a392367b16b197ca59a5017f5ecfb37ade2f26f4
Mar-24 20:15:22 DEBUG    CP Server Thread-4 :: Executing "/usr/local/git/bin/git" rev-parse HEAD with your shell in /Users/james/Applications/Sick-Beard
```

Git is indeed in /usr/local/bin/git.
The strange thing is that I don't recall changing anything that might have caused this issue - has anyone come across this issue before?
I've been through all the launchctl threads on these forums and have tried all the little personalised changes to plists and such, but none have really made any difference.

It appears to my untrained eye that python is demonising itself from the parent SickBeard processes, so it then is out of its jurisdiction to then stop when launched requests.

Your help and thoughts would be much appreciated!
If there's any further information I've missed that is of some use, please do let me know.

:)

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly daemonization but the `bin/python` executable in a standard Python OS X framework build is actually a launcher program that execs the real Python executable located within an app bundle in the framework:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

You *might* be able to get the behavior you desire by changing the launchctl plist to execute that executable directly.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Ned. I changed the two plists including the new binary, unloaded, reloaded, stopped and started, but python still doesn't stop unfortunately. If it's of any help, the first few lines from Activity Monitor point at the following for an instance of python. /Users/james/Applications/Sick-Beard
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.  From a quick look at the source of SickBeard, I see several references to restart code.  No idea how well that plays with launchd.  Good luck!